# node.js and sql overkill for simple client-specific number tracking app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications

I need to write an app that allows any number of web clients to increment and decrement a number.  This, along with identifying info, gets sent to and stored on a server.  Concurrently, another app watches all updates from the clients and visualizes that data on another webpage.

This kind of problem is new to me, so I'm trying to figure out a decent way to do this, but also want one that isn't overkill.  It looks like using client-side javascript to write to server files via ajax might be a bit tricky, so I thought of node.js and a SQL database.  however, given how simple this app is I'm wondering if it's overkill.

I'm probably looking at about 100 max concurrent clients.  I want the data to persist so that I could revisualize a previous moment in time (or restart a crashed service w/o loosing data).

Would this be overkill?  I'm really just looking for a simple approach to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you propose sounds solid to me.  Node.js is pretty light, and you have your choice of many databases to connect to.

100 simultaneously connected clients is actually a significant amount of traffic anyway.